# Error creating plugin: org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.WasbAzureIaasSink

Tags: azure, hadoop, azure-hdinsight

I have created HDI (3.6) Spark(2.1.0) cluster in Azure and installed my custom application.

When I start my application, I am getting the following error in my custom application log.

Error log:-

```
2017-04-28 07:21:55.926 GMT+0000 WARN  [main] MetricsSystemImpl - Error creating sink 'azurefs2'
org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfigException: Error creating plugin: org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.WasbAzureIaasSink
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig.getPlugin(MetricsConfig.java:202)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.newSink(MetricsSystemImpl.java:528)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.configureSinks(MetricsSystemImpl.java:500)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.configure(MetricsSystemImpl.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.start(MetricsSystemImpl.java:188)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.init(MetricsSystemImpl.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.metrics.AzureFileSystemMetricsSystem.fileSystemStarted(AzureFileSystemMetricsSystem.java:41)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.initialize(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:1255)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2596)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2630)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2612)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:169)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$7.apply(Client.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$7.apply(Client.scala:123)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.<init>(Client.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.<init>(Client.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:509)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.SimpleSparkContext.<init>(SimpleSparkContext.scala:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:270)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1131)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1034)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at com.myapp.util.PxBeanContext.startup(PxBeanContext.java:49)
    at com.myapp.spark.Main$.liftedTree1$1(Main.scala:43)
    at com.myapp.spark.Main$.delayedEndpoint$com$myapp$spark$Main$1(Main.scala:42)
    at com.myapp.spark.Main$delayedInit$body.apply(Main.scala:38)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
    at com.myapp.spark.Main$.main(Main.scala:38)
    at com.myapp.spark.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:738)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.WasbAzureIaasSink
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig.getPlugin(MetricsConfig.java:195)
    ... 63 more
2017-04-28 07:21:55.926 GMT+0000 WARN  [main] MetricsSystemImpl - Error creating sink 'azurefs2'
org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfigException: Error creating plugin: org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.WasbAzureIaasSink
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig.getPlugin(MetricsConfig.java:202)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.newSink(MetricsSystemImpl.java:528)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.configureSinks(MetricsSystemImpl.java:500)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.configure(MetricsSystemImpl.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.start(MetricsSystemImpl.java:188)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.init(MetricsSystemImpl.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.metrics.AzureFileSystemMetricsSystem.fileSystemStarted(AzureFileSystemMetricsSystem.java:41)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.initialize(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:1255)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2596)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2630)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2612)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:169)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$7.apply(Client.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$7.apply(Client.scala:123)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.<init>(Client.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.<init>(Client.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:509)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.SimpleSparkContext.<init>(SimpleSparkContext.scala:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:270)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1131)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1034)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at com.myapp.util.PxBeanContext.startup(PxBeanContext.java:49)
    at com.myapp.spark.Main$.liftedTree1$1(Main.scala:43)
    at com.myapp.spark.Main$.delayedEndpoint$com$myapp$spark$Main$1(Main.scala:42)
    at com.myapp.spark.Main$delayedInit$body.apply(Main.scala:38)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
    at com.myapp.spark.Main$.main(Main.scala:38)
    at com.myapp.spark.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:738)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.WasbAzureIaasSink
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig.getPlugin(MetricsConfig.java:195)
    ... 63 more
2017-04-28 07:21:56.042 GMT+0000 INFO  [main] MetricsSystemImpl - Scheduled snapshot period at 60 second(s).
2017-04-28 07:21:56.042 GMT+0000 INFO  [main] MetricsSystemImpl - Scheduled snapshot period at 60 second(s).
2017-04-28 07:21:56.042 GMT+0000 INFO  [main] MetricsSystemImpl - azure-file-system metrics system started
2017-04-28 07:21:56.042 GMT+0000 INFO  [main] MetricsSystemImpl - azure-file-system metrics system started
2017-04-28 07:21:56.049 GMT+0000 WARN  [main] AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'context' defined in class path resource [system-config.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.spark.SimpleSparkContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.security.ProviderUtils.excludeIncompatibleCredentialProviders(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:278)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1131)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1034)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at com.myapp.util.PxBeanContext.startup(PxBeanContext.java:49)
    at com.myapp.spark.Main$.liftedTree1$1(Main.scala:43)
    at com.myapp.spark.Main$.delayedEndpoint$com$myapp$spark$Main$1(Main.scala:42)
    at com.myapp.spark.Main$delayedInit$body.apply(Main.scala:38)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
    at com.myapp.spark.Main$.main(Main.scala:38)
    at com.myapp.spark.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:738)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.spark.SimpleSparkContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.security.ProviderUtils.excludeIncompatibleCredentialProviders(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:270)
    ... 33 more
```

When doing search about this, I have found this [link](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/50450/which-jar-has-orgapachehadoopmetrics2sinkwasbazure.html), But I am unable to find the WindowsAzureTableSink.java using the following path as mentioned in the link.

```
ls -l /usr/hdp/2.6.0.2-76/hadoop/src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/metrics2/sink/
total 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2862 Mar 25 23:17 FileSink.java
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 19 18:59 ganglia
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6828 Mar 25 23:17 GraphiteSink.java
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1055 Mar 25 23:17 package-info.java
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: hello, did you figure out some solution?